# Expo App Fetch API not working in Production but working in Development

Tags: react-native, expo

So, I created my React Native Expo App. It is working fine while in development. However, when I build the apk for production using `eas build` for `android`, the fetch API is not working.
I have a login system and loader, when fetch API is called, loader is set to true and when the response is received, it is set to false. However, when I try to login using this apk, the screen is stuck at my loader. It does not even fail. Code for the login functionality is

```
const login = async () => {
try{
  setLoading(true);
  const res = await fetch(`${BASE_URI}/login`, {
    method : 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    credentials : 'include',
    body : JSON.stringify({
      name, 
      password 
    })
  });
  const data = await res.json();
  if(data.success === true){
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('name', name);
    setLoading(false);
    navigation.navigate('/', {state : data.data});
  }
  else{
    setLoading(false);
    alert(data.message);
  }
}
catch(e){
  alert(e.response.data.message);
  setLoading(false);
}
}
```

The `BASE_URI` is `https://api.deardiary.tech/`, so I do not think this is a problem with SSL certificate. I tried to see the logs of the server, but even the first log is not visible.

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
   try {
       console.log(new Date().getTime, "login request received");
       let {name, password} = req.body;
       console.log(new Date().getTime, {name, password});
   ....
```

Logging is working correctly since there are logs when I use my web app instead of RN expo app.

I have not tested this with the IOS Platform. Also, if it helps, the fetch API was not working for the emulator as well and was throwing the error `Network Request Failed` even during the development server, but it is still working fine for the development server in my android device using Expo Go app, though not working in production.

Are there any settings that I should be adjusting on my Android mobile?

Comment: I have this issue too. Thought you should know you're not alone.

Comment: We have the same issue, this was working on version 48 of expo sdk, but after updating to version 50 it stopped working.